Geometry nodes. How to select next connected vertex (or previous I want to select every connected vertex around)
I am trying to find a solution for selecting the next vertex in geonodes, here is an example of the maze where I want to get a selection of a connected vertex in my maze but have had no success so far
:(
I hope anyone has a solution to this "puzzle" since my knowledge is not good enough to find a solution myself. I tried to use proximity, but proximity doesn't bother about the connectivity of the vertex it selects everything around, I feel like proximity with a combination of some magic can help.

I think the ability to grow a selection from the chosen point can help a lot of people


I would guess you should search for Mesh Islands and the Accumulate Field node. But that's all I know so far. Hopefully it helps somehow

(Using Blender 4.2.1)

This proposal is providing the index list of connected vertices. To select only the vertices connected to a crossing with 3 ways, see Markus von Broady proposal.


The approach is based on the Edges of Vertex node, taking advantage that for this application, no more than 4 edges are connected to the same vertex. This node is encapsulated in the Group Node "Neighbor". It is called 4 times, with incremented Sort Index values ranging from 0 to 3. For the demonstration, the Group Node is storing the adjacent vertex index in a named attribute, labeled "N0" to "N3". For cases with less than 4 neighbors, -1 is stored instead for "missing" neighbors.

NB: Dark pink nodes are evaluated in Edge domain, while dark green nodes are evaluated in Point domain.
1. Edges are sorted by their Index by the Edges of Vertex node to pick different edges for different values of the Sort Index input.
2. Sample Index nodes connected to an Edge Vertices node are recovering the Index of the end points of an edge. One of these points is the one requested by the Store Named Attribute node. We are looking for the other one. The filtering process is to add both values returned by the Sample Index nodes and to subtract the Index of the point requested by the Store Named Attribute node.
3. The Edges of Vertex node is also providing how many edges are connected to a point through its Total socket. If this value is lower or equal to the Sort Index input, it means that the list of neighbors is exhausted. Using a Switch node, -1 is returned in this case.
Resources: (An alternative way using probes and the solution of Markus von Broady are included in this file)
(Blender 4.2.1+)

This seems like a perfect job for the "Blur" node:


If you don't want to select the original points, just subtract it from the calculated selection:

(must be a boolean subtract, because I'm taking advantage of implicit type coercion)

Very interesting approach!
